# What is the difference between using "" and '' and () when declaring variables?

Tags: perl

I've seen several different ways to declare variables in Perl:

```
my $scalarVar = ""; my $scalarVar = ''; my $scalarVar = (); my $scalarVar;
my @arrayVar  = ""; my @arrayVar  = ''; my @arrayVar  = (); my @arrayVar;
my %hashVar   = ""; my %hashVar   = ''; my %hashVar   = (); my %hashVar;
```

What is the difference between using `""` and `''` and `()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`""` and `''` evaluate to an empty string.

In scalar context, `()` evaluates to `undef`. Idiomatically, one would use `undef` instead of `()` when one knows it will be evaluated in scalar context.

In list context, `()` does nothing. It's used as a placeholder where an expression is expected. Conceptually, it's viewed as an empty list.

---

When assigning to a scalar, the value is copied into the scalar.

When assigning to an array, the contents of the array are replaced with the assigned scalars.

When assigning to a hash, the list to be assigned is expected to be a list of key-value pairs. The contents of the hash are replaced with the assigned key-value pairs.

---

Scalars are undefined when created, and arrays and hashes are created empty, so

```
my $scalarVar = "";     # Creates a scalar containing an empty string.
my $scalarVar = '';     # Creates a scalar containing an empty string.
my $scalarVar = undef;  # Creates an undefined scalar. Uselessly noisy code.
my $scalarVar = ();     # Creates an undefined scalar. Uselessly noisy and weird code. 
my $scalarVar;          # Creates an undefined scalar.

my @arrayVar  = "";     # Creates an array containing one scalar (an empty string).
my @arrayVar  = '';     # Creates an array containing one scalar (an empty string).
my @arrayVar  = undef;  # Creates an array containing one scalar (undefined).
my @arrayVar  = ();     # Creates an empty array. Uselessly noisy code.
my @arrayVar;           # Creates an empty array.

my %hashVar   = "";     # Warns. Makes no sense since a list of k-v pairs expected.
my %hashVar   = '';     # Warns. Makes no sense since a list of k-v pairs expected. 
my %hashVar   = undef;  # Warns twice. Makes no sense since a list of k-v pairs expected.
my %hashVar   = ();     # Creates an empty hash. Uselessly noisy code.
my %hashVar;            # Creates an empty hash.
```

Answer (score 5):

`""` and `''` are equivalent. Some people use `q()` for the empty string, as `''` might look like a single `"` in some fonts and confuse the reader.

`my $scalarVar = ()` and `my $scalarVar` are equivalent, you can add `my $scalarVar = undef` to the group. I'd prefer the second option as it's the shortest one.

`my @arrayVar = ''` is the same as `my @arrayVar = ('')`, i.e. it creates an array with one element, the empty string. `my @arrayVar = ()` and `my @arrayVar` are equivalent, they create an empty array, I'd again prefer the shorter variant.

For the hash, `my %hashVar` and `my %hashVar = ()` are equivalent (and I'd prefer the former). Assigning an empty string to a hash emits a warning:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ...
```

and is equivalent to

```
my %hashVar = ( '' => undef );
```

i.e. it stores the undef value under the empty string key.